# Problem in styling while using react-native-textinput-effects

Tags: react-native

Hi I want to render the Akira component but it's not displayed properly on the screen and it's covered by another component, can anybody help me with this problem?

I think the problem is related the styling of my main view as when I put my component outside this wrapper component it appears at the start of the page.

```js
 return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: moneyScoreLogo }} />

        <Text style={styles.text}>Charge your account  </Text>

        <Akira
          style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
          label={'amount'}
       
          borderColor={'#a5d1cc'}
          inputPadding={16}
          labelHeight={24}
          labelStyle={{ color: '#ac83c4' }}
        />
        <MainButton onPress={() => onButtonClicked(amount)}>Charge</MainButton>
        <Text style={styles.warning}>{warning}</Text>
      </View>
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: colors.gray03,
  },
  image: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 15,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  warning: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: colors.red,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the answer, I just removed the flex:1 from styles.wrapper and everything went well.